# Post API-- what are the steps that need to be followed once the code is created so that I can add data into a txt file through this API

Tags: python, api, flask

I am new to API, and get a tasks of creating POST API. I have created a code somehow.
I want to add data to the hello.txt through post API, So how will I do it?
Here is my code:

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/api/v1/resources/messages', methods = ['POST'])
def api_message():

   if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/plain':
       return "Text Message: " + request.data

   elif request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/octet-stream':
       return "Binary message written!"

   elif request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':

       f = open('F:\Asif_Ahmed\Projects\api\hello.txt',"w")
       f.write(request.data)
       f.close()
       return "JSON Message: " + json.dumps(request.json)

   else:
        return "415 Unsupported Media Type ;)"

app.run()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I want to add data into a txt file using api. So how will I do that?

Comment: @AsifAhmed there are different methods, you can pass the data as JSON, if it's just small info like some number or world you can use a URL variable..... In any case give me 2 minutes and I'll write an example passing via JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request #import flask library
from flask_basicauth import BasicAuth # import flask library for create basic authentication if needed
from flask_cors import CORS # import flask library Cross-Origin Resource Sharing that is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) #set-up cors for my app

#if you want use basic authentication you need set-up username and password
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = 'admin'
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'] = 'password'


basic_auth = BasicAuth(app)#set-up username and password for my app but in this case I'm not specifying yet in which API use them



@app.route('/api/v1/resources/add_messages', methods=['POST'])#create my POST api
@basic_auth.required# set-up basic authentication for this API, comment out if not needed
def update_credential ():
    json_credential=request.get_json()#get the JSON sent via API
    print (json_credential["message"])#get the node "message" of my JSON
    ###########
    #code to write in your file, you need write the json_credential["message"]
    ###########
    return ("ok")



if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1024, threaded=True)#start my flask app with local_host IP and specific port, if you don't specify the port it will run in the default port
```

In this case the JSON Input should be:

```
{"message":"your text"}
```

Please let me know if something is not clear, I even try this code on my local and the JSON is passed without problems.....

So you need run your python script and see that the API is running, if you had no JSON to send and was just a simple API that give back information you should have used even Chrome but in this case that you need send some JSON data I would advice you to use Postman.
See screenshot example:
[image]

Comment: Please let me know where to give input??

Comment: @AsifAhmed it's an API, you can use postman; I'll attach a picture on my post

Comment: As you i am in the office and dont have postman software. Is there any other subsititue...

Comment: @AsifAhmed Postman is free you can easily install it or you can use a chrome plugin: Advanced REST client: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo